# How to fix background-color covering the "z-index: -1" rule

Tags: html, css, z-index

With pure CSS code i generated some ribbons.

If u put a `background-color` or `background-image` to the ribbon's parent or html body, the ribbon `:after` and `:before` `border-color` is not shown for some reason, even with a `z-index: -1`.

The reason is that the `background-color` of the parent is hiding it but i can't find a solution using both, background-color and ribbon :after and :before border-colors.

The demonstration:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXOERg

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `z-index: -1` you position an object behind your background `<div/>` which has no stacking context. Give it a `z-index` and it will work:

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:blue;z-index:0">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Here is a [codepen fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJxMMR)

Comment: Thanks, it seems that setting the `z-index: 0;` on the parent is the right solution, i thought that `z-index` is by default **0** on any element in which is not set

Answer (score 9):

Add the parent element:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
```

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/edensharvit/pen/ZEGEMQZ?editors=1100) demonstrate it